# VS Code: Tailwind CSS - Warning "CSS class selector 'focus' not found"

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css

I'm using VS Code and coding with Tailwind CSS. But in VS Code I receive the following error:

```
CSS class selector 'focus' not found
```

My code:

```html
<input class="focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-600 focus:border-transparent">
```

[image]

Comment: I use Sublime Text and in my case, any Tailwind classes with focus: simply do not work. Would appreciate it if anyone could give a pointer!

Answer (score 0):

That is not necessarily an error but more of a warning. You might have an extension like CSS Peek which looks for the `focus` selector but it's not found. To answer [UX Andre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7362226/ux-andre)'s question, by default, the `focus` variant is enabled for the core plugins listed [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#focus). You can also extend the use of the `focus` variant by declaring it in the *variants* section of your `tailwindconfig.js`.